# how to eliminate tags in Output XML if the respective tags in Input XML are not present using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML:

```
<PostedOrder>
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <Email>abc@gmail.com</Email>
    <Sender>John</Sender>
    <Recepient>Mary</Recepient>
    <ShipTo>Delhi</ShipTo>
    <ShipFrom>Mumbai</ShipFrom>
    <ShipUnit>MAIL</ShipUnit>
</PostedOrder>
```

Output XML:

```
<PostedOrder>
    <OrderID>12345</OrderID>
    <Contact>abc@gmail.com</Contact>
    <SentTo>Mary</SentTo>
    <Sentfrom>John</Sentfrom>
    <To>Delhi</To>
    <From>Mumbai</From>
    <ShipUnitID>
        <LocationID>
            <Bid>
                <Domain>Buisness</Domain><!-- Hardcoded value-->
                <Xid>MAIL</Xid>
            </Bid>
        </LocationID>
    </ShipUnitID>
</PostedOrder>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PostedOrder>
            <xsl:for-each select="/PostedOrder">
                <OrderID><xsl:value-of select="ID" /></OrderID>
                <Contact><xsl:value-of select="Email" /></Contact>
                <SentTo><xsl:value-of select="Recepient" /></SentTo>
                <Sentfrom><xsl:value-of select="Sender" /></Sentfrom>
                <To><xsl:value-of select="ShipTo" /></To>
                <From><xsl:value-of select="ShipFrom" /></From>
                <ShipUnitID>
                    <LocationID>
                        <Bid>
                            <Domain>Buisness</Domain><!-- Hardcoded value-->
                            <Xid>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ShipUnit" />
                            </Xid>
                        </Bid>
                    </LocationID>
                </ShipUnitID>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </PostedOrder>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the above example, I have a requirement not to create the `<ShipUnitID>` and the subsequent child elements in the Output XML if the `<ShipUnit>` is missing in the Input XML using XSLT. Can someone please help me with this, I'm new to the XML transformations. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You haven't shown us the current XSL that is creating the `ShupUnitID` in the output.  Without that, how to you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: Please find the attached XSL

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not need the `<ShipUnitID>` element and it's children in the output, you can add `<xsl:if>` condition to check for `<ShipUnit>` before preparing the `<ShipUnitID>` element. Below is code for reference.

```
<xsl:if test="ShipUnit != ''" >
    <ShipUnitID>
        <LocationID>
            <Bid>
                <Domain>Buisness</Domain>
                <Xid><xsl:value-of select="ShipUnit" /></Xid>
            </Bid>
        </LocationID>
    </ShipUnitID>
</xsl:if>
```

To test this, we can modify the input XML to have 2 elements for `<PostedOrder>`, one with `<ShipUnit>` as a child and one without as below.

```
<PostedOrders>
    <PostedOrder>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Email>abc@gmail.com</Email>
        <Sender>John</Sender>
        <Recepient>Mary</Recepient>
        <ShipTo>Delhi</ShipTo>
        <ShipFrom>Mumbai</ShipFrom>
        <ShipUnit>MAIL</ShipUnit>
    </PostedOrder>
    <PostedOrder>
        <ID>23456</ID>
        <Email>xyz@gmail.com</Email>
        <Sender>Paul</Sender>
        <Recepient>Tom</Recepient>
        <ShipTo>Chennai</ShipTo>
        <ShipFrom>Bengaluru</ShipFrom>
    </PostedOrder>
</PostedOrders>
```

**Updated XSLT**: XSLT has been modified to match template `<PostedOrder>` instead of matching the root element `"/"` and thereby eliminating the need of the `<xsl:for-each>`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="PostedOrder">
        <PostedOrder>
            <OrderID><xsl:value-of select="ID" /></OrderID>
            <Contact><xsl:value-of select="Email" /></Contact>
            <SentTo><xsl:value-of select="Recepient" /></SentTo>
            <Sentfrom><xsl:value-of select="Sender" /></Sentfrom>
            <To><xsl:value-of select="ShipTo" /></To>
            <From><xsl:value-of select="ShipFrom" /></From>
            <xsl:if test="ShipUnit != ''" >
                <ShipUnitID>
                    <LocationID>
                        <Bid>
                            <Domain>Buisness</Domain>
                            <Xid><xsl:value-of select="ShipUnit" /></Xid>
                        </Bid>
                    </LocationID>
                </ShipUnitID>
            </xsl:if>
        </PostedOrder>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<PostedOrder>
   <OrderID>12345</OrderID>
   <Contact>abc@gmail.com</Contact>
   <SentTo>Mary</SentTo>
   <Sentfrom>John</Sentfrom>
   <To>Delhi</To>
   <From>Mumbai</From>
   <ShipUnitID>
      <LocationID>
         <Bid>
            <Domain>Buisness</Domain>
            <Xid>MAIL</Xid>
         </Bid>
      </LocationID>
   </ShipUnitID>
</PostedOrder>
<PostedOrder>
   <OrderID>23456</OrderID>
   <Contact>xyz@gmail.com</Contact>
   <SentTo>Tom</SentTo>
   <Sentfrom>Paul</Sentfrom>
   <To>Chennai</To>
   <From>Bengaluru</From>
</PostedOrder>
```

Comment: I'm having a situation to eliminate the trailing spaces for a value that is coming in from the input xml, Adding <xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> in the XSL did not help me. Please Suggest.

Comment: Try using `normalize-space()` function for the value in which you are getting trailing spaces. This function removes leading and trailing spaces. If the answer has worked for you, please accept the answer.